# Report Builder - Conditional Formatting

Tags: date, conditional-statements, report, expression, builder

I believe this may be really easy to solve, but I'm just getting to grips with Report Builder & Visual Studio.

My question is as follows;

'Date logged'- when the job was initially raised
'Date completed' - when the job was completed
'Date due' - a date given, almost like an SLA, where the job must be completed

I would like to add conditional formatting / expression that fills the 'Date due' field green except for when the 'Date completed' exceeds the date in 'Date due'.

So if it is overdue I want the field to be red.

Thanks,
JG

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I was able to get it to work with the following;

=IIF(A >= B , “Red” , “Green”)

A and B are the fields from my dataset.